# How to render textarea in correct size and auto expand while typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a `textarea` and I would like it to load in the size of the value that is already there, and also to automatically expand as I continue typing.

I found these two pieces of JavaScript code work well separately, but when I put them together, one of them stops working. How do I bind them together?

```js
    $("textarea").height( $("textarea")[0].scrollHeight );
    
$(document)
      .one("focus.autoExpand", "textarea.autoExpand", function() {
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = "";
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
      })
      .on("input.autoExpand", "textarea.autoExpand", function() {
        var minRows = this.getAttribute("data-min-rows") | 0,
          rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 10);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="textarea" class="autoExpand" rows='1' data-min-rows='1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</textarea>
```

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple jQuery codes to accomplish that.

```js
$('#textarea').on('change keyup keydown paste cut', 'textarea', function () {
        $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
    }).find('textarea').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='textarea'>
<textarea name="textarea" class="autoExpand" rows='1' data-min-rows='1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, a JavaScript solution can complex. You can simply use a `<span>` which adjusts its size automatically as you described, and make it editable by adding the `contenteditable="true"` property:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
</div>
```

However, if you want to submit the value as part of the form, you'll have to do so by yourself in JavaScript, but that's relatively easy. You can add a hidden field, and assign the value of the `span` to the hidden field in the `onsubmit` event of the form. The hidden field will be then submitted with the form.